# Android Dex Optimization and Method Count

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

I have an android project with many library projects added as a module.

And the number of methods in the project exceeds the limit of android (65k). I use the multidex for a solution. It didn't solve my problem.

And this is my build.gradle file.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled = true
}}
```

First, I tried to add MultiDex.install() into onCreate method in ApplicationContext file. And it didn't work.
And ApplicationContextNormal.java file is here;

```
public class ApplicationContextNormal extends ApplicationContext {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    MultiDex.install(this);
    super.onCreate();
}

}
```

Then, I tried to add MultiDex.install() into attachBaseContext method.

```
public class ApplicationContextNormal extends ApplicationContext {
...
   @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(base);
}
    ...
```

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml;

```
<application
    android:name="com.alyt.lytmobilenormal.connection.ApplicationContextNormal" 
...
```

Is it true that I should solve this problem Dex optimization way? I made to changes in the main project, not in my module projects. Or am I missing something?

Any idea?

Comment: You should post your dependencies here. You should try to keep your app under a single dex.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Change this: add `multiDexEnabled true` lose the `'='`

```
   defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Also your class should extend `Application` class

```
public class ApplicationContextNormal extends Application {}
```

Comment: If it is multidex, it should extend `MultiDexApplication` and add `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1` to the dependencies.